# webpack 5 load image dynamically from different folder

Tags: reactjs, webpack-5

I have a webpack 5 and react application and I have to chose a folder at runtime for images based on variable.
however I am able to define path using require but in final build images from all folder are included .

```
const AppConstantProvider = ({ children }) => {

    const ASSETS_DIR = IVI_CONSTANTS.THEME_CONSTANTS
  
    return (
      <AppConstantContext.Provider
        value={{ IVI_CONSTANTS , OTHER_CONSTANTS, CAMERA_CONSTANTS ,  ASSETS_DIR}}
      >
        {children}
      </AppConstantContext.Provider>
    );
  };

asset-folder1
asset-folder2
asset-folder3

<img src={require(`../../assets/${ASSETS_DIR}/${iconName}.svg`).default} />
```

but in final prod build all image from all folders are included in build

Comment: That's how it goes. 

Webpack can't possibly know which images your application might use from that folder, if you use `require.context` or similar, so it bundles up all of them.

Comment: How did you resolved this issue? I am also facing similar problem.